# Create Multiple 'PivotCharts' on One 'PivotTable'

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Within my Excel Spreadsheet I have a PivotTable which is based on data retrieved from a SQL query.

The PivotTable is made up of a series of customers, each with their own stock value.

I made a PivotChart, but as there are many customers, the lines on the Chart are unreadable.

I want to make an individual chart for each customer, however when I filter on one customer, every chart filters on that customer - not allowing me to do one chart for each

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, adding more than one PivotChart distorted the layout of the underlying data.

Therefore it is necessary to read the same data into the Excel spreadsheet twice to have a second PivotChart.